# Apache server doesnt accept https request from f5

Tags: apache, http, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, f5

When I try to perform a health check from F5 to reverse proxy, it fails and there are no errors in the error_log but only the following in the access_log
XX.XXX.XX.X - - [11/Feb/2020:12:40:00 -0700] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
XX.XXX.XX.X - - [11/Feb/2020:12:40:00 -0700] "-" 408 - "-" "-"

Note: My Reverse proxy is running on port #443

My reverse proxy is setup and enabled with SSL and TLS v1.2 with required Cipher suite but still no luck, it shows the above message in the access_log.

Can anyone help me with this issue at the earliest?

Comment: 408 is basically a timeout, so there may be some connection issue between both or F5 not correctly configured. Easiest way is to try to check static simple text file to non-SSL port and evolve from there to start discarting other issues.

Comment: I did try all the options and even changed my Apache running on port 80 but still no luck, still the connection times out. I have 2 other servers configured the same way, F5 load balancer configured on port 443 with SSL enabled but still my apache runs on port 80 and accepts the https request and sends the traffic to my application server without any issues. But the other 2 servers are not working with the same configuration. Is this something wrong on the server? Are we missing some other configuration?

Comment: is your monitor an HTTPS monitor instead of an HTTP monitor?  Have you tried sshing into the F5, dropping into bash, and doing an `openssl s_client -connect server:443` ?  That works like telnet in that it will let you type out a HTTP packet by hand and see the exact reply that comes back from the server, except it does the SSL/TLS negotiations.  Sometimes you need `openssl s_client -crlf -connect server:443` if your server replies after you hit your first enter while typing the http packet.
This will tell you if theres any network/firewall problems and if you're getting the expected response